# Pasting Range Object Returns Random Output

Tags: excel, vba

The copied range object is not pasting correctly and despite extensive reading plus trialing different fixes over several days, I still can't explain it. Current paste output seems totally random and uncorrelated to any data from the source Workbook.

Attempts include:

1. Debugging (works in debug mode)
2. Checking all variables are properly declared
3. Activating appropriate Worksheet
4. Inserting DoEvents in various places
5. Stopping short of `Select` or `Selection` as that seems ridiculous

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub McOpen()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        ' Part 1
        
            Dim Fusion As Workbook, _
                MC As Workbook, _
                ws1 As Worksheet, _
                ws2 As Worksheet, _
                ws3 As Worksheet, _
                Rng As Range, _
                file As String
    
                Set Fusion = ThisWorkbook
                Set ws3 = Fusion.Worksheets("[Sheet1]")
                Set ws1 = Fusion.Worksheets("[Sheet2]")
                file = ws1.Range("C19")
                
                Set MC = Workbooks.Open(file)
                Set ws2 = MC.Worksheets("[Sheet3]")
                Set Rng = ws2.Range("A1:AB45")
            
        ' Part 2

            Rng.Copy
            With ws3
                .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Activate
            End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Hesitant to open this question on Stack due to trivial nature of problem and a dented ego, but what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try rename your sheetname as it does not require to set as array, and also make sure your path name on `C19` is valid one, I am getting the expected result with your code:

**From:**

```
Set ws3 = Fusion.Worksheets("[Sheet1]")
                Set ws1 = Fusion.Worksheets("[Sheet2]")
                file = ws1.Range("C19")
                
                Set MC = Workbooks.Open(file)
                Set ws2 = MC.Worksheets("[Sheet3]")
```

**To:**

```
Set ws3 = Fusion.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Set ws1 = Fusion.Worksheets("Sheet2")
                file = ws1.Range("C19")
                
                Set MC = Workbooks.Open(file)
                Set ws2 = MC.Worksheets("Sheet3")
```

Complete code by change sheetname only:

```
Sub McOpen()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        ' Part 1
        
            Dim Fusion As Workbook, _
                MC As Workbook, _
                ws1 As Worksheet, _
                ws2 As Worksheet, _
                ws3 As Worksheet, _
                Rng As Range, _
                file As String
    
                Set Fusion = ThisWorkbook
                Set ws3 = Fusion.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Set ws1 = Fusion.Worksheets("Sheet2")
                file = ws1.Range("C19")
                
                Set MC = Workbooks.Open(file)
                Set ws2 = MC.Worksheets("Sheet3")
                Set Rng = ws2.Range("A1:AB45")
            
        ' Part 2

            Rng.Copy
            With ws3
                .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Activate
            End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

**Fusion Sheet2:**

[image]

**Fusion Sheet1:**

[image]

**MC Sheet3:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kin Siang. Sorry for confusion, the brackets were meant to indicate a generic sheet name. I still had no luck after fully defining the variable `file` by amalgamating its file string and folder name into the file path. Since it performs as expected for yourself, would there be some obscure settings changed by an system-wide upgrade perhaps?

Comment: You may see my above example for all the sheet. You can start try with very basic testing as above , it will work perfect then you can start develop more complicate function from that, give a test first, it is 100% working and reproductive.

Comment: Found it but isn't truly related to Q posed. The Workbook copying from had set calculations to manual; after promptly writing a single line to convert to automatic everything was fine. Thanks for assistance in brainstorming, @Kin Siang.

Answer (score 0):

Found it but isn't truly related to Q posed. The Workbook copying from had set calculations to manual; after promptly writing a single line to convert to automatic everything was fine.